# Local analycity of p-adic power.

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Let $u \in \mathbb C_p$, $|u|<1$. It is easy to see that the function $n \mapsto (1+u)^n$, $\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb C_p$ uniquely extends to a continuous function $f: \mathbb Z_p \rightarrow \mathbb C_p$. One customarily uses the notation $(1+u)^z$ for $f(z)$.

I am looking for an elegant proof, or a reference to any proof, of the following well-known fact:

> The function $z \mapsto (1+u)^z$ is locally analytic.

This means that there exists an $r>0$ and coefficients $a_n \in \mathbb C_p$ such that $|a_n|r^n$ goes to  $0$ when $n$ goes to infinity and $(1+u)^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ for all $z \in \mathbb Z_p$, $|z| \leq r$. This should be easy, but the proof I came up with seems way too computationally complicated, especially for the teaching purpose I have.

Comment: I didn't get the point was to find a power series in $z$ (easy for $|z|_p < 1/(p-1)$ using $\log,\exp$ but much less obvious for $|z|_p \le 1$). What is the argument of your complicated proofs ? What about $|f^{(k)}(z)|_p$ with $f(z) = (1+u)^z$ ?

Comment: I thought I would be able to dispose of this easily, but my first glance does not give me an answer. I’ll think on it.

Comment: reuns, yes exactly, this is easy for $|z|_p < 1/(p-1)$! For the general case, my method is writing $(1+u)^z=\sum_{k=1} z(z-1)...z(-k+1)/k! u^k$ and the coefficients $a_{k,n}$ of the polynomial $z(z-1)...z(-k+1)/k!$ are essentially Stirling number of the first kind for which I found bound in some rather recent literature, which allows me to rewrite $(1+u)^z$ as $\sum_n (\sum_k a_{k,n} u^k) z^n$ and checks that it converge. But there got to be a simpler way for this results that I see everyone in the field of p-adic analysis using as if it is trivial.

Comment: do we still have a theorem saying that if a sequence $(f_n')$ converges uniformly to $g$ then the sequence $f_n$ converges to $f$ with $f'=g$ ?

Comment: I think I have it, and without anything as fancy as Stirling. Unfortunately, I’m busy as anything, and may not have time to put it up till (at worst) tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s almost essential to use, instead of absolute value, additive valuation $v=v_p$, normalized so that $v(p)=1$. You’re asking about $(1+u)^z$, for fixed $u$ with $v(u)>0$, as a $\Bbb C_p$-series in $z$.

Now, as a series in two variables, $(1+u)^z\in\Bbb Q_p[z][[u]]$, but we want to look at it as an element of $\Bbb Q_p[[u]][[z]]$. You’ve written this as $\sum_na_nz^n$, suppressing the dependence of the $a_n$’s on $u$.

At least one of the commenters pointed out that it would be nice to know $\frac{\partial^n}{\partial z^n}(1+u)^z$; but we all know that $\frac\partial{\partial z}(1+u)^z=(1+u)^z\log(1+u)$, formally, in $\Bbb Q[[u,z]]$. Therefore,
$$
\frac{\partial^n}{\partial z^n}(1+u)^z=\bigl(\log(1+u)\bigr)^n(1+u)^z\,.
$$
Now, still in $\Bbb Q_p[[u]][[z]]$, we have
$$
(1+u)^z=\sum_n\frac{\bigl(\log(1+u)\bigr)^n}{n!}z^n=\sum_n\frac{\bigl(z\log(1+u)\bigr)^n}{n!}\,,
$$
which all of us knew already, but we didn’t believe it.

Specializing $u$ to a constant, the criterion for convergence of this $z$-series is that $v\bigl(z\log(1+u)\bigr)>1/(p-1)$. You may need to reassure yourself that $v\bigl(\log(1+u)\bigr)$ does not get out of hand. But the dependence of this valuation on $v(u)$ is well understood: if $v(u)\ge1/(p-1)$, then $v(\log(1+u))\ge v(u)$, and if the first inequality is strong, then the inequality on the valuation becomes an equality. Similarly,
$$
\text{if}\quad\frac1{p^{n+1}(p-1)}\le v(u)\le\frac1{p^n(p-1)}\quad
\text{then}\quad v\bigl(\log(1+u)\bigr)\ge p^nv(u)-n\,,
$$
and again, if the conditions are both strongly satisfied, the conclusion becomes an equality.

I think that should do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Professor Lubin for this answer, and your comment above.

Comment: My pleasure. Of course, there’s a 2-line proof: since $(1+u)^z=\exp\bigl(z\log(1+u)\bigr)$ formally, you need only guarantee that $v\bigl(z\log(1+u)\bigr)>1/(p-1)$. But I don’t think I would have believed that proof.

Comment: This was the first proof I came up with (for notes of a course). Then I stopped believing in it. My faith has not completely come back yet. In fact I am still troubled with the proof you give. So your estimate on $v(log(1+u))$ shows that if $v(z)$ is large enough (w.r.t $v(u)$ which is fixed), then the series $\sum_n (z(\log(1+u))^n)/n!$ converges. But how do we know it is equal to the LHS $(1+u)^s$? In fact, if $u=\zeta_p-1$, it seems to me that the terms are not equal, for $\log(1+u)=0$ so the RHS is 1 while the LHS is $(1+u)^z$ which is not constant for $v(z)$ small.

Comment: Hmmm — let me think on this!

Comment: Well, your first objection gives me pause, but your example does not: For that particular $u$, if $v(z)$ is small, the series in question is not convergent and gives us no information; if $v(z)$ is large, then $z=pz'$ and $(1+u)^z$ factors through $(1+u)^p=1$. But lookit: if you think an e-mail exchange might clear our confusions, by all means send me a message, and we can discuss.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.